# How to format Maxwell equations?

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

Is there a variant of `split` environment from `amsmath` package which would allow for two aligned equations in a row? I want to format two pairs of Maxwell equations in two rows and put single equation number between the rows. Unfortunetely, `split` allows only one alignment tab `&` in a row, and I need three as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rot}{rot}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{18.1:1}
    %\begin{split}
        \Rot\vec{E} &=-\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{B}}{t}
        ,
        &
        \Div\vec{B} &=0,
        \\
    \label{18.1:2}
        \Rot\vec{B} &=\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{E}}{t}
        +\frac{4\pi}{c}\,\vec{j}
        ,
        &
        \Div\vec{E} &=4\pi\rho_{\varepsilon }
    %\end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here every row has its own number.

Comment: Your code is not compilable: `\parder` is nowhere defined. Also, you may want to use a more descriptive name for your labels, and it's best to precede punctuation marks such commas and full stops by a `\,`.

Comment: The `\parder` is defined as: `\newcommand{\parder}[2]{\frac{\partial {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}`.

Comment: @m0nhawk, thank you, indeed, i've missed the definition of `parder`.

Comment: @Jubobs, Sorry, I didn't ask how to format punctuation marks or how to choose names for labels.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you. That was just a side note that I thought could be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are after `aligned`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rot}{rot}
\newcommand{\parder}[2]{\frac{\partial {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{18.1:1}
  \begin{aligned}
    \Rot\vec{E} &=-\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{B}}{t},&
    \Div\vec{B} &=0,
    \\
    \Rot\vec{B} &=\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{E}}{t}
    +\frac{4\pi}{c}\,\vec{j},&
    \Div\vec{E} &=4\pi\rho_{\varepsilon}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rot}{rot}

\newcommand\parder[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{18.1:1}
\begin{split}
\Rot\vec{E} &=-\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{B}}{t},
\\
\Div\vec{B} &=0,
\end{split}
\\[2ex]
\label{18.1:2}
\begin{split}
\Rot\vec{B} &=\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{E}}{t}+\frac{4\pi}{c}\,\vec{j},
\\
\Div\vec{E} &=4\pi\rho_{\varepsilon }
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution.